# Can I configure Mutter to unredirect fullscreen windows?

Tags: 10.10, unity, performance, mutter

I tried a Google search on the subject; however I came up with nothing. Is there a way I can enable this option so I can enable good 3d performance while using Unity?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might be to just use compiz instead of mutter. They way you can do that is to install ubuntu-tweak, find the session-control and replace mutter with compiz --replace.

Make sure you have compiz and compizconfig installed. In the compiz config settings, go to general, and choose undirect fullscreen windows.

To DIRECTLY answer your question, I don't think mutter can do that as yet.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of such. I suppose I am glad they decided on Compiz then. Can't wait for Natty. :)

Comment: lol same here =D

Comment: btw you do know you can run unity without mutter?